# Векторы в gtkmm 3.0

Tags: c++, gtkmm3

Файлы такие:

#### main.cc

```
//g++ main.cc -o main `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` -lstdc++fs
#include "mainwindow.cc"
#include "catalog.cc"

#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <gtkmm/application.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto app = Gtk::Application::create("org.gtkmm.example");

  MainWindow window;

  return app->run(window, argc, argv);
}
```

#### mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef GTKMM_MAINWINDOW_H
#define GTKMM_MAINWINDOW_H

#include <gtkmm.h>

#include "catalog.h"

class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
  public:
    MainWindow();
    virtual ~MainWindow();

protected:

  void add_catalog();

  //Child widgets:
  Gtk::Box m_mainBox;
  Gtk::Grid m_grid;

  Catalog *m_Catalog0 = new Catalog("/var/www/cscart.site");
  Catalog *m_Catalog1 = new Catalog("/var/www");
  Catalog *m_Catalog2 = new Catalog("/var/www/cscart.site");
  Catalog *m_Catalog3 = new Catalog("/var/www");

  Gtk::ButtonBox m_bottom_buttons_box;
  Gtk::Button m_button_add;

};

#endif //GTKMM_MAINWINDOW_H
```

#### mainwindow.cc

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow()
: m_mainBox(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL),
  m_button_add("+")
{
  set_title("FM 4x4");
  set_border_width(5);
  set_default_size(500, 500);

  add(m_mainBox);  
m_mainBox.pack_start(m_grid);
m_grid.attach(*m_Catalog0, 0, 0, 1, 1);
m_grid.attach(*m_Catalog1, 1, 0, 1, 1);
m_grid.attach(*m_Catalog2, 1, 1, 1, 1);

m_grid.remove(*m_Catalog0);
m_grid.attach(*m_Catalog0, 0, 0, 1, 2);

  m_mainBox.pack_start(m_bottom_buttons_box, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);
  m_bottom_buttons_box.pack_start(m_button_add, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);

  m_bottom_buttons_box.set_border_width(5);
  m_bottom_buttons_box.set_layout(Gtk::BUTTONBOX_END);
  m_button_add.signal_clicked().connect( sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MainWindow::add_catalog) );

  show_all_children();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
}

void MainWindow::add_catalog() {
  //m_leftBox.pack_start(*m_Catalog3);
  m_grid.remove(*m_Catalog0);
  show_all_children();
}
```

#### catalog.h

```
#ifndef GTKMM_MAIN_CATALOG_H
#define GTKMM_MAIN_CATALOG_H

#include <gtkmm.h>

class Catalog: public Gtk::ScrolledWindow {
    public:
        Catalog(std::string p);
        virtual ~Catalog();
        void set_path(std::string p);

        class ModelColumns : public Gtk::TreeModel::ColumnRecord {
            public:
                ModelColumns() {
                    add(m_col_name); add(m_col_extension_or_dir_or_file);
                }
                Gtk::TreeModelColumn<std::string> m_col_name;
                Gtk::TreeModelColumn<std::string> m_col_extension_or_dir_or_file;
        };
        ModelColumns m_Columns;

    Gtk::TreeView m_TreeView;

    protected:
        Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::ListStore> m_refListStore; //The Tree Model.
};
#endif //GTKMM_EXAMPLE_MESSAGESLIST_H
```

#### catalog.cc

```
#include "catalog.h"

#include <experimental/filesystem>

Catalog::Catalog(std::string p) {

    set_policy(Gtk::POLICY_AUTOMATIC, Gtk::POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
    set_hexpand(true);
    set_vexpand(true);

    /* Обязательно поправить это недоразумение */
    set_border_width(1);

    add(m_TreeView);

    m_refListStore = Gtk::ListStore::create(m_Columns);
    m_TreeView.set_model(m_refListStore);

    Gtk::TreeModel::Row row;

    namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
    std::string path = p;
    for (auto & p : fs::directory_iterator(path)) {
        row = *(m_refListStore->append());
        row[m_Columns.m_col_name] = fs::path(p).filename();
        row[m_Columns.m_col_extension_or_dir_or_file] = fs::path(p);
    }

    m_TreeView.append_column("Name", m_Columns.m_col_name);
    m_TreeView.append_column("Extension", 
m_Columns.m_col_extension_or_dir_or_file);
}

Catalog::~Catalog() {
}
```

А вопрос такой:

Я хочу эти 4 экземпляра:

```
Catalog *m_Catalog0 = new Catalog("/var/www/cscart.site");  
Catalog *m_Catalog1 = new Catalog("/var/www");  
Catalog *m_Catalog2 = new Catalog("/var/www/cscart.site");  
Catalog *m_Catalog3 = new Catalog("/var/www");
```

заменить вектором класса. Как мне это сделать?

конструкция вида:

```
std::vector{Catalog^} arr;  
arr.push_back(new A(2));  
arr[0];
```

не работает.

Хотя тестовый файл с такой конструкцией отрабатывает нормально.

Comment: А в чём собственно вопрос?

Comment: Все же написано. Я хочу, чтобы я имел возможность объявить вектор <Catalog*>, добавлять/удалять элементы, обращаться к элементам вектора. Хочу заменить *m_CatalogN на v_catalog[N].

Comment: Да, только вопрос стало возможным прочитать только после правки пользователя Fat-Zer, который отформатировал ваш код, до этого же вопрос был скрыт под кодом и до него нужно было очень долго листать. Можете посмотреть первую редакцию в истории чтобы понять что я имею в виду.

Comment: .... Я же вас не спрашиваю о визуальном редакторе этого сайта. Я просто не знаю как оформлять.

Comment: `std::vector{Catalog^} arr;` - это на каком языке?

Comment: Какие вы придирчивые: std::vector<Catalog*> arr; Это визуальный редактор не принимал запись.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Определение вектора в классе вполне обычное:

```
class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window {
public:
   MainWindow();
//...
   std::vector<Catalog*> catalogVec;  
}
```

Для инициализации классическим решением будет несколько `push_back`'ов в конструкторе:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow() /* : ... */ {
  catalogArr.push_back(new Catalog("/var/www/cscart.site"));
  catalogArr.push_back(new Catalog("/var/www"));
  // ...
}
```

В новых версиях C++ есть также варианты:

- Инициализация при объявлении:

  ```
  class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window {
  //...
     std::vector<Catalog*> catalogVec = {  new Catalog("/var/www/cscart.site"), 
                                           new Catalog("/var/www"} 
                                        };
  }
  ```
- Инициализация в списке инициализации конструктора:

  ```
  MainWindow::MainWindow() :
  // ... 
    catalogVec ({new Catalog("/var/www/cscart.site"), new Catalog("/var/www")});        
  {
    // ...
  }
  ```

Но при таком подходе ответственность за указатели лежит на программисте. И эти объекты необходимо явно уничтожить в деструкторе (если конечно `gtkmm` об этом само не заботится как `Qt`; TODO: свериться с документацией).

```
MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
  for (auto cat: catalogveg) {
    delete cat;
  }
}
```

Вместо этого я бы рекомендовал использовать [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: не могу обратиться к элементу вектора. Не срабатывает: m_grid.attach(catalogVec[0], 1, 0, 1, 1);

Comment: Раз я не могу создать вектор.... Быть может я могу определить имя экземпляра каким-нибудь string'ом? Что-то типа этого: for(int i=0; i<=3; i++){ Catalog *string_to_name('name'.i) = new Catalog (path[i]);}

Comment: я не особо знаю специфику gtkmm, но судя по коду выше, `Gtk::Grid::attach` принимает объект по значению или ссылке. так что должно быть `m_grid..attach(*catalogVec[0], 1, 0, 1, 1);` — забыл разыменовывать указатель...

Comment: Вы правы. Большое спасибо. А я все думал, что раз я звездочку добавил в угловатые скобочки, то все элементы - уже указатели.

Comment: @6apa6awka, если вопрос закрыт, то стоит ответить ответ «правильным», дабы он не болтался...